# Ошибка JS "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null "

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста! Пишу тетрис на JS и все время выдает ошибку! Я новичок, поэтому не пинайте за мой код.

Эта функция отвечает за движение объектов:

```js
function move(){
 //START MOVE FLAG FO FIGURE
    moveFlag = true;


 let coordinates = [
  [bodyFigure[0].getAttribute('posX'), bodyFigure[0].getAttribute('posY')],
  [bodyFigure[1].getAttribute('posX'), bodyFigure[1].getAttribute('posY')],
  [bodyFigure[2].getAttribute('posX'), bodyFigure[2].getAttribute('posY')],
  [bodyFigure[3].getAttribute('posX'), bodyFigure[3].getAttribute('posY')],
 ];

 for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++){
  if (coordinates[i][1] == 1 || document.querySelector(`[posX = "${coordinates[i][0]}"][posY = "${coordinates[i][1]- 1} "]`).classList.contains('set')) {//Проблемное место
   moveFlag = false;
   
   break;
  }
 }

 if (moveFlag) {
  for (let i = 0; i < bodyFigure.length; i++) {
  bodyFigure[i].classList.remove('figure');
 }
 bodyFigure = [
  document.querySelector(`[posX = "${coordinates[0][0]}"][posY = "${coordinates[0][1] - 1}"]`),
  document.querySelector(`[posX = "${coordinates[1][0]}"][posY = "${coordinates[1][1] - 1}"]`),
  document.querySelector(`[posX = "${coordinates[2][0]}"][posY = "${coordinates[2][1] - 1}"]`),
  document.querySelector(`[posX = "${coordinates[3][0]}"][posY = "${coordinates[3][1] - 1}"]`),
 ];
 for (let i = 0; i < bodyFigure.length; i++) { 
  bodyFigure[i].classList.add('figure');

 }
}
 else{
  for (let i = 0; i < bodyFigure.length; i++) {
  bodyFigure[i].classList.remove('figure');
  bodyFigure[i].classList.add('set');
 }
 create();
}
 
}


setInterval(() => {
 move();
}, 300);
```

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: Arial;
}

.tetris{
 position: absolute;
 width: 500px;
 height: 900px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: #FFF;
 overflow: hidden;

}
.main{
 margin: 50px auto;
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 height: 700px;
 border:1px solid black;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.excel{
 width:50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.figure, .set{
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main"></div>
        <script src="game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Причем ошибка вылезеает при указании ЛЮБОГО класса! Я проверял синтаксис, вроде нормальный. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.Ошибку выдает эта сточка: if (coordinates[i][1] == 1 || document.querySelector(`[posX = "${coordinates[i][0]}"][posY = "${coordinates[i][1]- 1} "]`).classList.contains('set'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибка говорит что не получилось найти элемент с таким селектором.
проверьте, точно ли нужен пробел здесь `[posY = "${coordinates[i][1]- 1} "]` - между `} "`
ну и потом, если пробел и правдп нужен, что элемент такой существует

Comment: Спасибо огромное!  Проблема была в пробеле!